# Cut and move a part of an image in inkscape

Tags: plot, inkscape

I've an image like the one in the following link

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-an-image-using-text-align/

I want to cut and move one half of the image close to the other (one building close to the other in the example image share above). In real case, I have a similar image with white space in between. To cut one part of an image I do Object-> Clip -> Set on the selection. This crops the selection alone. But I am not sure how to select and move the `selection`.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What kind of image? Is it a vector graphic or a raster graphic?

Comment: @Moini a raster graphic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duplicate the image, then clip both images to the two parts that you need. Then use snapping to move them both together exactly.

Or (better), use a raster graphics editing tool of your choice and do the same. While the above-described workflow *works*, Inkscape, being a vector graphics editor, is not the appropriate tool for this kind of thing.